# Nexus Sonatype "Cleanup Old Snapshots" fails

Tags: nexus

I'm working on a Nexus 1.9.2.3 implementation and we're trying to run the Scheduled Task "Cleanup Old Snapshots".

The task runs anywhere from 2-5 mins and then fails with an "Error [XmYs]" in Last result (where X and Y are minutes/seconds values).

Logging shows that the tasks starts and is waiting, then no failure results shown in the logs (both nexus.log and wrapper.log).

We're trying to remove an excessively large collection of snapshots from the system that have been allowed to accumulate over the years, and ultimately move to just keeping the last 10. Next step will be to perform an upgrade to a newer version. But this has become a bit of a work blocker.

I'm at my whits end on this end on this and am close to just manually deleting all the files but I know that doesn't cleanly clear all the meta information out so it's a last resort option.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the files on the filesystem and run a scheduled task to update the Maven metadata.

And then upgrade Nexus as soon as possible. You are using a VERY old version.

Comment: So just delete all the old files manually and run "Rebuild Maven Metadata Files"?

Comment: Yes... that will rebuild the maven metadata for whatever remains. Probably also update the index of the repo after.